# Avoid form submission if no input value changed

Tags: jsf, jsf-2

Is there any way in JSF2 we can avoid the form submission,
or simply do not do anything when form is submitted?

We have several input fields (20 input fields) in a form,
which are filled with some default values,
if no value is changed then we don't want to submit the form.

Is there any direct way in JSF we can achieve this?

```
<h:form id="summaryForm" prependId="false">
     <h:inputText id="inputField1" value="#{summaryBean.inputFieldValue1}" />
     <h:inputText id="inputField2" value="#{summaryBean.inputFieldValue2}" />
     <h:inputText id="inputField3" value="#{summaryBean.inputFieldValue3}" />
     <h:inputText id="inputField4" value="#{summaryBean.inputFieldValue4}" />
     <h:inputText id="inputField5" value="#{summaryBean.inputFieldValue5}" />
     <h:commandButton action="#{summaryBean.submitSummary}" />
</h:form>
```

Comment: If you have default value map, in action method you can compare them. If values are not changed return null; which displays same view, otherwise return "nextview"

Comment: you mean the default values whatever we have at initialization phase.
hmm yeah we have a lot of values, then we might need to save all those values for comparison purpose. apart from that is there any way in jsf either at client side or server side.

Comment: Without comparison with existing value it is hard to figure out the change, so either client/server side you need to do this comparison.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The short answer is no, in plain JSF you can't do that.
You can do it on the client side with a bit of JavaScript and [jQuery](http://www.jquery.com), though.

```
... include jQuery somewhere here ...

<script>
var anyInputChanged = false;
var checkIfAnyValueChanged = function(){ return anyInputChanged; };
(function($) {
    $(function() {
        // set variable anyInputChanged to TRUE on event 'onchange',
        //    for the fields with class "submitOnlyIfChanged"
        $('.submitOnlyChanged').change(function(){ anyInputChanged = true; });
    });
})(jQuery);
</script>

<h:form id="summaryForm" prependId="false">
    <!-- set up all the fields with the class "submitOnlyIfChanged" -->
    <h:inputText class="submitOnlyIfChanged" id="inputField1"
       value="#{summaryBean.inputFieldValue1}" />
    <h:inputText class="submitOnlyIfChanged" id="inputField2"
       value="#{summaryBean.inputFieldValue2}" />
    <h:inputText class="submitOnlyIfChanged" id="inputField3"
       value="#{summaryBean.inputFieldValue3}" />

    <!-- set up a check if any field was changed on button click -->
    <h:commandButton onclick="return checkIfAnyValueChanged();"
       action="#{summaryBean.submitSummary}" />
</h:form>
```

Comment: This is what absolutely i am looking for.
Even if there is no option in JSF still ok, we can use this way.
Thank you so much @eljunior.

Answer (score 0):

Simple approach.

```
var allFields = document['formName'].elements;
var submit = document.getElementById("submit");
submit.disabled  = true;
var fieldsValue = [];
var x;
var y=0;
for( var i=0; i<allFields.length; i++ ){
    fieldsValue[i] = document.forms["formName"][allFields[i].name].value;
    document.getElementsByName(allFields[i].name)[0].addEventListener('input', function (evt) {
        x = fieldsValue.indexOf(this.value);
        x < 0 ? y = y+1 : y = y-1;
        y > 0 ? submit.disabled  = false : submit.disabled  = true;
    });

}
```

Comment: And what if you have 25 fields?

Comment: @Kukeltje , you can check it out. now it dynamically works on every fields of the form.